# Show events in fullcalendar using ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-core, fullcalendar

I am writing application on asp.net core 2.0. and trying to show events stored in DB in calendar. I have added links to js and css files as it is shown in documentation. As event source I am using events as function as it is shown in official documentation [Fullcalendar Doc](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/events_function/) but my calendar does not show events. It is empty!

`GetEvents` method in `Schedules` controller which gets data from DB

```
    public ActionResult GetEvents()
    {
        return new JsonResult(Json(from events in _context.Schedules
                                   select new { id = events.ID,
                                                EventTitle = events.EmployeeID,
                                                ShiftDate = events.ShiftDate.Date } ));
    }
```

I also tried to modify ajax but it also does not work.

```
<div id="calendar"></div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
             events: function (start, end, timezone, callback) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/Schedules/GetEvents",
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "JSON",

                    success: function (result) {
                        var eventsList = [];
                        // alert(result);                 // --1--
                        // alert(JSON.stringify(result)); // --2--
                        $(result).each(function () {
                            var eventTitle = $(this).attr('EventTitle');
                            var eventStart = $(this).attr('ShiftDate');
                            var eventId = $(this).attr('id');
                            eventsList.push(
                                {
                                    id: eventId,
                                    title: eventTitle,
                                    start: eventStart
                                });
                        });
                        if (callback)
                            callback(eventsList);
                    }
                });
            }

        });
    });
</script>
```

First `alert` shows message `[Object object]...`, Second `alert` shows all selected data in a "JSON string". But calendar does not show anything. 
So, what am I doing wrong? Thank you!

Comment: Why are you using jquery to iterate over the response? and I don't understand the `$(this).attr('EventTitle')` part. Should not it be
`result.forEach(function (item) {
eventsList.push({
id: item.id,
title: item.EventTitle,
start: item.ShiftDate,
})
})`

Comment: `$(this).attr('EventTitle')` gets `EventTitle` field for each element in `result`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
result.forEach(function (item) { 
  eventsList.push({ 
    id: item.id, title: item.EventTitle, start: item.ShiftDate 
  }) 
})
```

Comment: I tried and got an error "Uncaught TypeError: result.forEach is not a function" in Chrome console. Changed `result.forEach(function (item) {...})` to `Array.prototype.forEach.call(result, function (item) {...});` but still the same. Calendar is empty.

Comment: what output did you get from alert(JSON.stringify(result));?

Comment: selected data from database. [{"id":1,"eventTitle":"First Last","shiftDate":"2018-01-24-T00:00:00"}, ...] and so on. I have 6 test rows in my DB and they all are selected (as in linq query).

Comment: It's odd that forEach is not a function then. There is also Array.from(result), but probably not going to help either. Another thing I'd check is what's in eventsList before you invoke the callback.

Comment: Remove `new JsonResult` from controller. I checked `eventsList` before `callback` and it was not empty. but calendar shows nothing (((

Comment: double checked the doc, `start` should be a unix timestamp, try
`start: new Date(item.ShiftDate.replace('-T', 'T')).getTime()/1000`

Comment: @HermanStarikov "start should be a unix timestamp"...it can be that, but not necessarily. It can be anything the momentJS constructor will accept. An ISO date such as "2018-01-24 00:00:00" would be perfectly fine. Gor stated that their JSON contains "2018-01-24-T00:00:00" which doesn't look to be valid (extra dash before the T) (see https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/ for details) but it also doesn't look like what ASP.NET would produce, unless it's changed in .NET Core. Your idea should work but no need to make it a timestamp I don't think.

Comment: It does not work even with constant values `start: "2018-01-24 00:00:00"`. Also I got "undefined" message before `callback` `alert(JSON.stringify(eventsList[0].title));alert(JSON.stringify(eventsList[0].start));`.

Comment: @GorAsatryan "Also I got "undefined" message". What exactly did it think was undefined? Without seeing exactly what you're doing it's hard to help with vague descriptions like this.